# display:none property not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<tr style="height:5px" id="TRRSHeaderTrialBar" name="TRRSHeaderTrialBar" style='display:none'>
<tr id="TREmail" name="TREmail"  style="height:1px;" nowrap style='display:none'>
```

i use the above code to hide the bar and it is working fine in IE but not in firefox and chrome
so i used

```
document.getElementById("TREmail").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("TRRSHeaderTrialBar").style.display = "none";
```

`TRRSHeaderTrialBar` contains tabpages and `TREmail` contain two buttons.
When the page loads, `TRRSHeaderTrialBar` works fine but `TREmail` shows the buttons when the page starts loading. After loading is finished, it hides.

I want to hide that buttons when page is loading.

Comment: Your markup is invalid: [There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are a case-insensitive match for each other.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attribute)

Comment: Why do you have 2 times style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [must not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attribute) use multiple style attributes. Instead of

```
 <tr style="height:5px" ... style='display:none'>
```

use

```
 <tr style="height:5px; display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the html code you have written; you can easily notice that there are two styles in both the `tr`.
Try following, it might work:

```
<tr style="height:5px; display:none;" id="TRRSHeaderTrialBar" name="TRRSHeaderTrialBar">
<tr id="TREmail" name="TREmail"  style="height:1px; display:none;" nowrap>
```

You must apply all the css styles in one style heading, as mentioned in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
varvalidated = document.forms(0).validated.value;

if(varvalidated == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("k1").style.display = "none";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("t1").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Add some description and code formatting for improved readability.